# Kendo Spreadsheet - Change event not firing

Tags: events, kendo-ui, telerik, spreadsheet

[In Kendo Telerik UI documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/ui/spreadsheet#events-change) , Telerik claims that the change event has been added into the Spreadsheet component.

That event is not firing though.

Please check it out into this DOJO example:
http://dojo.telerik.com/adEKO

> --------- SOLUTION -------------

The syntax was correct, but i was using the wrong version of Kendo. 
This is the correct working case: http://dojo.telerik.com/adEKO/11

Comment: This feature will be introduced in the 2016 Q1 SP1 release. which has not been released yet. It should be here shortly so I would say watch this space. I would imagine it will be released in the next couple of weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your onchange is a method but you are not using it as such. 
change: onchange,
should be
change: onchange(),

Got it to fire just fine after adding the Parenthesis.

Comment: you re right. my mistake. you know what the funny thing is ? That official telerik support answers me to the same question , that the "onchange"  event will be introduced in 2016 Q1 SP1 in march, but seems to be working fine :)))

Comment: Yeah, I just ran into a similar issue earlier yesterday. I hate it but I don't get much out of their support staff, it seems very scripted with their replies but that's why we have "The Stack".
I am glad I could help you!

Comment: sorry, seems that the onchange function is fired only during the page load.  but not during the  change event. but i remember that it worked though. may be something related to kendo.all.min.js version?

Comment: maybe, I had to bind the change event to the grid but ran into the change event gets called a lot! Just by simply clicking into the cell calls the change event.
Here is the link I found to reference:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/observableobject#events-change

Comment: i added a final comment up and a link to the dojo in the original question. it works without parenthesis and it is needed to use at least version 2016.1.225 to work.